# AWS CLI and MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

I have created an IAM user (without MFA) and attached the below policy to the user. This is to make sure that the calls to the S3 use MFA. But, when I use the AccessKeys for this user via the AWS CLI, I am able to perform the S3 operation `aws s3 ls` with out any authorization error.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in AWS?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try `Bool` in place of `BoolIfExists`. A condition with the latter will evaluate to true if the condition key is absent.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why the policy statement in the OP is not working. But,
I did attach the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy with one of the below policy and it behaves as expected. For the `long-term credentials` I am not able to perform S3 operations and for the `temporary credentials` when authenticated with MFA I am able to perform the S3 operations.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, my OP was about "Effect/Allow" and I was asking the community why it was not working. Did you respond why "Effect/Allow" as mentioned in the OP was not working? If you see any problem in the policy statement in the OP, lease let me know.

Comment: I explained that you need Deny, not Allow. Your answer does not even link to AWS docs which explain such a policy and why Deny is needed.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `Allow`, but you should be using `Deny` as explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-7). Example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/taxdocuments/*",
        "Condition": { "Null": { "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": true }}
      }
    ]
 }
```

Read the AWS docs **carefully**, as you can lock yourself out of the bucket if you use `Deny` incorrectly.

Comment: If the MultiFactorAuthPresent is set to true then I am allowing the access to the bucket. I am not sure what the problem with the policy I posted in the OP.

Comment: @PraveenSripati Because `Allow` is not a `Deny`. You need to have deny just like aws docs explain to enforce MFA.

Comment: Allow is not a Deny. Very funny.

Comment: How do we give the access to the user without "Effect": "Allow" ?

Comment: @PraveenSripati You wrote in the question that you have access already without MFA. So now you have to just deny any such access, which will enforce the use of MFA.